# Colour horizontal bars on a seaborn plot based on the y-axis with seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

So before anyone says, I'm not trying to create a horizontal bar plot. I'm trying to make a scatter graph that categorises the different plots based on the y values.

So this is my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random

f = []

for i in range(10):
    f.append(random.randint(60,80))

df = pd.DataFrame({
"Weight": f, "Dates": ["01/12/20", "05/11/20", "12/02/20", "18/09/20", "22/04/20", "19/01/20", "18/02/20", "02/01/20", "28/11/20", "26/03/20"]
}, columns=["Weight", "Dates"])

df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"])

df.sort_values(by="Dates", inplace=True, ascending=True)

sns.set_theme(style="dark")

dates = [datetime.datetime.date(x) for x in df["Dates"]]

graph = sns.stripplot(data=df, x=dates, y="Weight")
graph.set_xticklabels(graph.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

So this is the current output:

[image]

But I want to be able to add some bars so I can categorise the data like (sorry for my poor drawing):

[image]

I still want to see the points afterwards, but I don't care about what colour they are.

I don't know if this is possible, but thanks!

EDIT: Answered by tmdavidson in comments.

Comment: How do you determine what the height of the bars should be? You could add some matplotlib [`Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) patches on your axes. Or use [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html). And either add them with a zorder below your scatter plot, or given them a transparency (alpha) so you can see the scatter plot behind them.

Comment: Thanks, the rectangle bit suggestion worked. Just trying to get it sorted now

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [axhspan](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhspan.html) that was made for this very purpose

```py
bands = [77.5,72.5,67.5,60]
colors = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10')(range(len(limits)))
for y1,y2,c in zip(bands[0:], bands[1:], colors):
    graph.axhspan(ymin=y1, ymax=y2, color=c, zorder=0, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]